# Metro style,how to make my screen compatible for landscape and portrait mode?

Tags: windows-phone-7, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I am new to metro style app.I designed a normal page in **visual studio 2012 ultimate** in landscape mode using only drag and drop tools.I run this page using Emulator.It runs well in landscape mode.but In Portrait mode,the contents of the page is not fitted automatically.Even it is not allowed to scroll the screen to see all the contents in the page.

I want a design **fits for all screen resolution and different orientation**. what should i do?
If any tutorial available please provide the link.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about Windows Phone or WinRT?

Either way, you need to handle the orientation change yourself.

If you're doing WinRT, start here:

[Optimizing for both landscape and portrait](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/10/20/optimizing-for-both-landscape-and-portrait.aspx)

and if you're doing Windows Phone, start here:

[How to: Handle Orientation Changes on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769553%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)